# Where are the Canned Response in the new format?

Tags: gmail, gmail-canned-response

Got to the new Google Mail format. I have Canned response enabled in Labs - but I can't figure how to add/use them!

Anyone?

Comment: Agree with poster. There is no way to save a new canned response with the new compose window.

Comment: It's there. Read the answer

Comment: Confirmed. Create new option is the last option in italics before "Delete". Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Canned responses have moved to the additional menu next to the "Discard Draft" or Trashcan button.

Click on the triangle at the bottom right of the new compose window to open the menu and then hover over "Canned Responses" to view all of your options.

[image: screen shot of "More Options" menu]